# link with href=“#” scrolls page to top when used with hammer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I am using hammer in my javascript to attach event as shown below.

```
$('.get-stats').each(function() {
    Hammer(this).on('tap', function(e) {
        //my code
        window.location.href="http://myurl.com";
    });
});
```

The issue I am facing is when I click or tap the  tag, it first navigates to the top of the page and then only redirects to my url.
I tried e.preventDefault(); but its not working.

Any ideas??

Comment: <a class="get-stats" href="#" style="-moz-user-select: none;">Get Stats</a>

Comment: Remove the href attribute which is causing this. You can use CSS `cursor:pointer` to get the correct cursor on mouseover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `href="#"` to `href="javascript:void(0)"`.

This will surely help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove **href="#"**, since it is what's navigating you to top.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep `href` empty like

```
<a class="get-stats" href="" style="-moz-user-select: none;">Get Stats</a>
```

as you are performing the operation in JS.

I guess `#` is the culprit here. Remove it and your code should work fine.